# How can I make my .bashrc call to shopt -s autocd depend on the bash version?

Tags: bash, bashrc, shopt

In Ubuntu I like having

```
shopt -s autocd
```

in my `.bashrc` file for automatic CD'ing with typing 'cd', i.e. just type the directory name (and probably use tab completion too) and press return and be cd'd to the directory if it exists.

On OSX this isn't valid in my `.bashrc`

How can I do a 'depends on' for this? So that I can share and maintain just one .bashrc between the two OS's ?

I know for a file I can do stuff like:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

and for an application like tmux that depends on screen I can do

```
if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
  if [ -n "$(type -P tmux)" ]; then
    exec tmux
  fi  
fi
```

but I can I do this kinda thing for whether I can do `shopt -s autocd` ?

Comment: check $BASH_VERSION >= 4 perhaps?  Seems poor way though.

Comment: Switching on `uname -s` might be enough.

Comment: Is it a fatal error? If not, just silence it.

Comment: @Michael testing for the feature or bash version seems much better than checking the OS.  What if you upgrade the version of bash on your Mac?  (Which is probably the better solution BTW.)

Comment: How do I write the version test? I've tried dozens of different attempts but can't get the syntax right..

Comment: @MichaelDurrant did you try `[[ $(uname) -eq Linux ]] &&  shopt -s autocd` as I suggested below?

Comment: I did thanks you.  I was nervous that `$ [[ $(uname) -eq dsdss ]] &&  echo 'y'` returned 'y'

Comment: Yes, that's cause I'm an idiot. Sorry, try the updated answer, the `-eq` does integer comparison, not string. `[[ $(uname) = dsdss ]] &&  echo 'y'` will not echo anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autocd` was introduced into bash [with version 4](http://freecode.com/projects/gnubash).  So, a general cross-platform solution should be:

```
[ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -ge 4 ] && shopt -s autocd
```

`${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}` is bash's major version.  The minor version, should you ever need it, is `${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}`.  See `man bash` for more on `BASH_VERSINFO`.

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as

```
shopt -s autocd 2>/dev/null
```

If you want to see whether an option is available but not change its value, call `shopt` without `-s` or `-u`:

```
if shopt autocd >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then …
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to check the OS name and act accordingly. I don't know what `uname` will return on OSX but presumably it will be different. You can therefore do something like this:

```
 [[ $(uname) = Linux ]] &&  shopt -s autocd
```

That said, are you sure you need to do this? OSX runs login shells by default and the `~/.bashrc` is ignored unless you have modified your `~/.profile` to source it. Therefore, if you have something in your `~/.bashrc`, it will only run on Linux anyway.

Comment: +1 for useful info.  downvote not from me.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant heh thanks :) The original downvote was merited since I was using `-eq` instead of `=`.