# How can I prevent unsupported 'shopt' options from causing errors in my .bashrc?

Tags: bash, shell-script, configuration, shopt

I work in a relatively heterogeneous environment where I may be running different versions of Bash on different HPC nodes, VMs, or my personal workstation. Because I put my login scripts in a Git repo, I would like use the same(ish) `.bashrc` across the board, without a lot of "if this host, then..."-type messiness.

I *like* the default behavior of Bash ≤ 4.1 that expands `cd $SOMEPATH` into `cd /the/actual/path` when pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. In Bash 4.2 and above, you would need to `shopt -s direxpand` to re-enable this behavior, and *that* didn't become available [until 4.2.29](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-05/msg00148.html). This is just one example, though; another, possibly related `shopt` option, `complete_fullquote` (though I don't know *exactly* what it does) may have also changed default behavior at v4.2.

However, `direxpand` is not recognized by earlier versions of Bash, and if I try to `shopt -s direxpand` in my `.bashrc`, that results in an error message being printed to the console every time I log in to a node with an older Bash:

```
-bash: shopt: direxpand: invalid shell option name
```

What I'd like to do is wrap a conditional around `shop -s direxpand` to enable that option on Bash > 4.1 in a robust way, without chafing the older versions of Bash (*i.e.*, not just redirecting the error output to `/dev/null`).

Comment: How my answer did not help?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini It did, and that's the solution I ended up going with in my own `.bashrc`. I still wanted a record of how to use `$BASH_VERSINFO` to interrogate the major/minor version of the running shell, for my own edification, which is why I finished posting my own answer. `:)`

Comment: Look in my answer i have something about comparing programs version with shell script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if `direxpand` is present in the output of `shopt` and enable it if it is:

```bsh
shopt | grep -q '^direxpand\b' && shopt -s direxpand
```

Comment: Better make that `grep -q '^direxpand\b'` in case some future version or fork of bash has an option that contains this as a substring _and_ removes `direxpand`. Unlikely in this specific case, but it doesn't cost much to be robust.

Comment: Thanks Luciano. I'd intended to answer my own question, but I"ll accept your answer after my edits go through peer review. Maybe you can approve them yourself?

Comment: Bash allows to query specific shell options, so one can use `[ -z "$(shopt -po direxpand 2>&-)" ] || shopt -s direxpand`. No more regex issues! :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster I'd turn the logic around: `[ -n "blah" ] && shopt blah` The way you phrase it, you're saying "if direxpand is unsupported, then don't do this thing".

Comment: @Rich: Most of my shell scripts include `set -e` at the top, so I tend to use short-cut logic this way around.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Good eye. I had never scrutinized the output of `help shopt` that closely before, but I think you need to leave out the `-o` which restricts the output to options "defined for use with `set -o`"—which `direxpand` is not. A shame the return value of `shopt` is non-zero for both unset _and_ invalid options, otherwise `-q` (suppress output) could've also come in handy.

Answer (score 18):

I don't see what's wrong with redirecting errors to `/dev/null`. If you want your code to be robust to `set -e`, use the common idiom `… || true`:

```
shopt -s direxpand 2>/dev/null || true
```

If you want to run some fallback code if the option does not exist, use the return status of `shopt`:

```
if shopt -s direxpand 2>/dev/null; then
  … # the direxpand option exists
else
  … # the direxpand option does not exist
fi
```

But if you really dislike redirecting the error away, you can use the completion mechanism to perform introspection. This assumes that you don't have antiquated machines with bash ≤ 2.03 that didn't have programmable completion.

```
shopt_exists () {
  compgen -A shopt -X \!"$1" "$1" >/dev/null
}
if shopt_exists direxpand; then
  shopt -s direxpand
fi
```

This method avoids forking, which is slow on some environments such as Cygwin. So does the straightforward `2>/dev/null`, I don't think you can beat that on performance.

Comment: That is _not_ where my brain would've gone, but I like the `compgen` proposal. That's varsity level stuff right there! Avoiding redirection to `/dev/null` is just a personal preference. I like to ask for permission instead of forgiveness, if that makes sense? `:)`

Comment: +1 for a totally unanticipated schooling in Bash programmable completion, which forced me to go to the manual to decipher what `compgen -A shopt -X ...` even meant.

Comment: @TheDudeAbides I read about using `compgen` this way on [unix.se], I don't know who first proposed it. (I stopped using bash as my main shell before it had programmable completion.) In programming it's usually a bad idea to ask for permission because there's a risk that the permission check will not match what you're actually doing, either because of a coding error (where you aren't quite checking what you think you're checking) or because [what you checked changed before you used it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

Answer (score 6):

When you know for sure that a specific [`shopt` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) is available at a certain major/minor/patch release of Bash, you can inspect the `$BASH_VERSION` variable or the elements of the `$BASH_VERSINFO[]` array in order to enable it conditionally.

Here's a test for Bash 4.2.29 or greater, the version where `direxpand` [was first introduced](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-05/msg00148.html) to the 4.2 series:

```bsh
if [[ $BASH_VERSION == 4.2.* && ${BASH_VERSINFO[2]} -ge 29 ]] ||
   [[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -eq 4 && ${BASH_VERSINFO[1]} -ge 3 ]] ||
   [[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -ge 5 ]]; then
    shopt -s direxpand
fi
```

***Edit:** To be clear, this is a ridiculously over-engineered solution for simply ignoring an error message coming from your login scripts, but I did want to document it regardless, for my own edification.*

Note the braces around `${BASH_VERSINFO[index]}`, which *are* required, and the use of `-eq` and `-gt`, which do integer rather than (locale-dependent) lexical comparisons. If unquoted, the RHS of the `==` operator is treated as "extglob" patterns within Bash `[[`/`]]` conditionals, as noted [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html), which makes a more aesthetic "starts with" comparison than a regex would, IMO.

The [`$BASH_VERSINFO` array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fVERSINFO) contains all the information you'd see in the output of `bash --version`:

```bsh
bash --version | head -1
# result:
# GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

declare -p BASH_VERSINFO
# result:
# declare -ar BASH_VERSINFO='([0]="4" [1]="3" [2]="48" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")'
```

When it *isn't* clear from the documentation for `shopt` at which Bash version(s) became supported or changed their behavior, the method proposed by Luciano is fine:

```bsh
# note the '-q' so that the matched pattern isn't actually printed
shopt | grep -q direxpand && shopt -s direxpand
```

...as is the solution proposed by Gilles of just ignoring the error (`shopt -s direxpand 2>/dev/null`), and perhaps checking `$?` if absolutely necessary.

References: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124424/how-can-i-make-my-bashrc-call-to-shopt-s-autocd-depend-on-the-bash-version), [2](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html), [3](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html)
Related reading: [Set and Shopt - Why Two?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32409/set-and-shopt-why-two)

Comment: You might also be able to use something like `if [[ $BASH_VERSION > 4.3 ]];` (which matches `4.3.0`, `5.0` etc., but also `4.3.0-alpha`. I don't know if the later fact matters.)

Comment: Hi @ilkkachu. Thanks for your edit to cover Bash v5.x. The `direxpand` option is indeed available for Bash 4.2, though; I've verified this with a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash?tab=tags) at v4.2.53 by running `docker run --rm bash:4.2 bash -c shopt | grep direxpand` (and, for good measure, that it is indeed _not_ available at v4.1.17 by running `docker run --rm bash:4.1 bash -c shopt | grep direxpand`).

Comment: ah ok, I tested `4.2.0` and stumbled upon the fact that it didn't work there. The [changelog](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) also mentions it added in `bash-4.3-alpha`. I suppose then that one would need to check `${BASH_VERSINFO[2]}` to be exact about it, but I don't know which point release added it...

Comment: I think we've basically proved the point Gilles made above; that it is, in fact, better to just _try_ to enable the shell option, and then deal with the error (or suppress it) if it isn't supported.