# How to expand tab-completion for environment variables in bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have an environment variable stored in my .bash_profile called $MODULES:

```
MODULES='/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/
```

When I am at the bash prompt and I type `cp $MOD` and then press TAB to complete, how do I get it to expand to:

```
sudo cp /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/
```

...and then I can immediately continue on with a subfolder and tab-complete that as well? Right now, when I do TAB completion it resolves to:

```
sudo cp \$MODULES/
```

...which means it's looking for a directory in the current location named "$MODULES", which is obviously not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the relevant Bash shell option with `shopt -s direxpand` to expand directory variables to its full path using tab completion. Add that line to your `.bashrc` to make the option permanent.

Appending the variable with a forward slash is required before pressing tab.

Comment: This was previously the default behavior in Bash before 4.2. I believe there are still supported macOS versions out there with `/bin/bash`es this old, so you may wish to put `shopt | grep -q '^direxpand\b' && shopt -s direxpand` in your `~/.bashrc` to account for both Bash < 4.2.29 and Bash ≥ 4.2.29, where `direxpand` was introduced. [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498859/278323)